# Ubuntu 20.04 Dell Precision 7540 does not boot with 5.8.0_34 kernel

Tags: boot, kernel, dell

Booting using the 5.4.0-60 kernel works fine but neither of the more recent kernels
(5.8.0-34 and 5.8.0-36). The boot process stops on displaying a 'DELL' screen.
I can find options for removing the newer kernels and freezing the kernel at 5.4.0-*. Is there a better solution or any way to find out what is hanging?

Comment: You can either stick with the 5.4 kernel, or find out what is wrong with the 5.8? Are you using an Nvidia GPU?

Comment: I can explain how to remove the 5.8 kernel.

Comment: Hi - my preference is to find out what is wrong with it. I spent a while yesterday trying to do that. I edited /etc/default/grub to add 'nomodeset' - this had no effect. I also added GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text" and GRUB_TERMINAL=console to see if I could get something on the screen. dmesg doesn't show me any errors, and I have not found anything obvious under /var/log. The boot process does not get as far as the purple screen, it seems to stop very early. Weird, if you have any ideas I'll follow them up.

Comment: What is your GPU? Is it Nvidia?

Comment: I think not:zoe@zoes:/var/log$ sudo lshw -numeric -C display
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: TU117GLM [Quadro T1000 Mobile] [10DE:1FB9]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation [10DE]
       .....
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile) [8086:3E9B]
       vendor: Intel Corporation [8086]
       .....
I believe this is telling me that I am not using NVIDIA

Comment: So it is Nvidia as you can see.

Comment: You have an Nvidia adapter, but the driver isn't installed because it's incompatible with the 5.8 kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Run in a terminal

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-460
```

That should install a compatible Nvidia driver.

Comment: Thanks, that does get it to boot. The screen is very dark and the wifi adapter does not seem to be recognised but I guess they are different problems :-)

Comment: The wifi and screen brightness problems were both fixed by udo apt install linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-36-generic. Thanks again for your help.